# Get parent table from field object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I get parent table class from field object? Just `.parent` method doesn't work as expected, e. g.:

```
class SomeTable(Base): # Base have 'query' manager field
    somefield = Column(...)

def subroutine(field):
    table = field.parent # ????
    # should work exactly as
    # table = SomeTable
    table.query.filter(...)

subroutine(SomeTable.somefield)
```

Comment: Why don't you pass `SomeTable` itself to `subroutine` func ? rather than field value ?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Why don't you just use a session to form a query using the passed field directly?

Comment: @IljaEverilä session is hidden under `.query` interface. Nevertheless I need Table class to use session to form a query as well

Comment: @SijanBhandari since I need both field and table in subroutine, and wish to avoid redundancy in interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QueryableAttribute.parent`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.QueryableAttribute.parent) returns an inspection instance representing the parent, which is either an instance of [`Mapper`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper) or [`AliasedInsp`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.util.AliasedInsp) depending on the nature of the parent entity. It does not return the mapped class directly, as you seem to have expected. You can access the mapped class through the [`class_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper.class_) attribute:

```
def get_parent_class(attr):
    return attr.parent.class_
```